# Which version of Xcode supported in iPhone XR

Tags: xcode

the iPhone XR is running ios 12.4.1(16G102),which may not be supported by this version of Xcode

the running version of Xcode is 10.14

Comment: I doubt the version of Xcode is `10.14` because the current version is `10.2.1` or something close to that. You've probably got `10.1.4` (note the added dot).

Comment: Xcode 11.0 and newer should support iOS 12.4.1 devices.

Answer (score 2):

You can download zip from [here](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/blob/master/DeviceSupport/12.4%20(16G73).zip) and unzip it. And copy to dir `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`.

Final restart Xcode, your Xcode will support iOS 12.4.1 device